# Does anyone have Kivy running on Raspberry Pi4 /raspios (Raspbian) Buster Lite

Tags: kivy, raspberry-pi4, raspbian-buster

I have a Kivy App running satisfactorily on Raspberry Pi3/ArchLinux (without desktop).
I am now attempting to move the App onto a Pi4 running Buster Lite.  I have followed the guide/notes (faithfully, I believe) posted at kivy.org [here](https://kivy.org/doc/master/installation/installation-rpi.html.), particularly the part about compiling sdl2 from source, with the kmsdrm option set.

However, kivy reports that it is 'unable to find any valuable window provider'.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-07-11_22.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[DEBUG  ] [Text        ] Provider <pango> ignored by config
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Provider <egl_rpi> ignored by config
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Provider <x11> ignored by config
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'No available video device'
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 981, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 290, in create_window
    self.get_gl_backend_name())
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 110, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 74, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I have tried the two available settings for the gl driver in raspi-config - G1 Legacy and G2 GL (Fake KMS), but neither option offers an improvement.

If anyone can identify what I've done wrong, or offer advice on how to resolve the problem, I would be very grateful.

Edit:

The INFO messages are a little confusing - does this:

`[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)`

mean that the sdl2 Window provider is ignored completely?  If so, that would explain my problem.  How would I prevent sdl2 from being ignored?

Comment: This might be more suitable for [raspberrypi.se] instead, as it's about video configuration.

Comment: @Ken White - perhaps but, as I understand it, the Pi4 has new issues in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try with Kivy 2.0. I guess the latest one is Kivy 2.0.0rc3.
Check: https://kivy.org/doc/master/installation/installation-rpi.html.